# Parse Server : Client Key : Logging in via Javascript

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

So, coming back to a project, so have forgotten a few things.  I have a Parse Server hosted.  It has a Web front end, iOS and Android.

I use iOS to create the initial admin user.  To do this I need to include
**.clientKey** in the configuration.  But I thought once I made that user.  I should be able to remove this setting and login normally

The user is created by (details are not real)

```
 var newUser = PFUser()

    newUser.username = "simon"
    newUser.password = "simon"
    newUser["admin"] = 1
    // Sign up the user asynchronously
    newUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeed, error) -> Void in

        // Stop the spinner
        if ((error) != nil) {
            var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Error", message: "\(error)", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            alert.show()

        } else {
            var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Success", message: "Signed Up", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            alert.show()

        }
    })
```

None of the created users can login via the web interface?  Do I need to add some sort of **.clientKey** to that end to?  This all worked on the previous server so thats why I am confused

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that you can't login via the web interface, but your code is trying to "create" a user by using the signUpInBackgroundWithBlock function.  You should be able to login users on the web interface if the user object exists in the database (it was created by any other interface), but you should try using the login function:

```
Parse.User.logIn("simon", "simon", {
  success: function(user) {
    // Do stuff after successful login.
  },
  error: function(user, error) {
    // The login failed. Check error to see why.
  }
});
```

The client key is not used on the hosted parse server.  You don't really need to set it in any of the platforms (although I think on Android, there was a bug if you set it to null, so you needed to set it to "").

Comment: The user does exist but wont login I get unauthorised access

Comment: Hmm seems I am getting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: I think this may be the answer https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard/issues/480